# ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.middleware.user

Tags: django, django-cms

I have just installed django-cms with pip install, and now, when I try to access the admin page, am getting the following error with no luck with using other solutions to this problem (many that involved changing path variable) for the past few hours

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flup- 1.0.3.dev_20110405-        py2.6.egg/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 574, in run
protocolStatus, appStatus = self.server.handler(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flup-1.0.3.dev_20110405-py2.6.egg/flup/server/fcgi_base.py", line 1159, in handler
result = self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/mcgillme/lib/python2.6.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/mcgillme/lib/python2.6.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.10-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    raise exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured('Error importing middleware %s: "%s"' % (mw_module, e))
ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing middleware django.middleware.page: "No module named page"
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Type: text/html
```

I looked through other solutions, so I checked my cms installation - the folder middleware exists and contains an **_init**.py file.

$PATH and $PYTHONPATH seem to include the cms as well, because, for example this works:

```
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Nov 22 2013, 12:16:22) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cms
>>> import django.middleware
>>> import django.middleware.page
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named page
>>>
```

What else can it be besides a missing path? How can django.middleware work, but django.middleware.page is not found?

Answer (score 0):

I look into every django version from 1.2 to 1.7 and there is no `django.middleware.page`,  but it is in `django-cms`.

Use `cms.middleware.page`

Answer (score 0):

Did you add cms to your INSTALLED_APPS environment variable in settings.py?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = {
    'cms',
}
```

After checking, maybe u can run this command again to make sure it's installed:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - Yes, cms is under INSTALLED_APPS and python manage.py syncdb worked okay and prompted me to create a superuser which I did

Answer (score 0):

1. CHECK THIS:[Removed the MultilingualMiddleware](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.3/upgrade/2.4.html#removed-the-multilingualmiddleware)
2. IT SAYS THE SOLUTION COULD BE:

> Remove cms.middleware.multilingual.MultilingualURLMiddleware from your settings.
>
> Be sure django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware is in your settings, and that it comes after the SessionMiddleware.